# Not understanding variables

Tags: c++, string, debugging, variables

My instructor gave us this assignment

Develop a C++ program that uses variables and cout to output your first name, major, number of credit hours, and per credit hour tuition rate.
1.  Use 4 variables of the appropriate type initialized with the values for your name, major, credit hours and tuition rate.
2.  Variable names must be descriptive
3.  Use cout to output the values of the variables to the console. Your cout statement MUST use the 4 variables
4.  Output must be labelled and easy to read as shown in the sample output below.
5.  Program must be documented with the following:
a.  // Name
b.  // Date
c.  // Program Name
d.  // Description

After reading this chapter I submitted the assignment. My code was as follows:

```
//Cassandra Hamric
//January 20, 2016
//Defining Variables
//Outputwill show name, major, credit hours and tuition rate

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int name;
int major;
int hours;
int tuition;
name = Cassandra;
major = Health Information Technology
hours = 16;
tuition = $146.28

cout<<"My name is " << name << endl;
cout<<"I am majoring in " << major <<endl;
cout<<"I am taking" <<hours "credit hours" << endl;
cout<<"I am paying" << tuition "per credit hour" <<endl;
cout<< endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When I submitted this my instructor said that there were no variables and that I needed to do the assignment over. I have re-read the chapter, looked at notes and searched online... This is the new code I came up with...

```
//Cassandra Hamric
//January 20, 2015
//Defining Variables
//Output will show name, major, credit hours and tuition rate

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myName;
    string major;
    short credithours;
    float tuitionrate;

    myName = Cassandra;
    major = Health Information Technology;
    credithours = 16;
tuitionrate = $146.28;

cout <<"My name is" << myName << endl;
cout <<"I am majoring in" << major << endl;
cout <<"I am taking" << credithours "credit hours" << endl;
cout <<"I am paying" << tuitionrate "per credit hour" << endl;
cout << endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

I have so many errors that come up now and I do now know how to fix them. I have attached pictures with the errors on bottom and the debugging error I get. Does anyone know how to solve these problems in the most basic of terms and also am I using the variables correctly for this assignment?

[image: Debugging Error]

[image: General Programming Errors]

Comment: You need to put quotes around `Cassandra` and `Health Information Technology` (i.e., they should be `myName = "Cassandra";` and `major = "Health Information Technology";`). Further, don't use `$` when storing the value of a `float`.

Comment: `float` is a type that stores numeric values, it's up to you to define what units those values represent. C++ has no concept of dollars, so `tuitionRate = $146.28` is completely invalid C++. Ditch the $ symbol.

Comment: Your instructor was wrong about there being no variables...

Answer (score 4):

```
//Cassandra Hamric
//January 20, 2015
//Defining Variables
//Output will show name, major, credit hours and tuition rate

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myName;
    string major;
    short credithours;
    float tuitionrate;

    myName = "Cassandra";
    major = "Health Information Technology";
    credithours = 16;
    tuitionrate = 146.28f;

    cout << "My name is " << myName << endl;
    cout << "I am majoring in " << major << endl;
    cout << "I am taking " << credithours << " credit hours" << endl;
    cout << "I am paying $" << tuitionrate << " per credit hour" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You just had some problems while initializing string variables and writing cout's.